# How to exit from thread which is suspended by semaphore?

Tags: c, multithreading

In main function I create one producer thread and two consumer threads.
Producer doing some work, then with "if" statement checks if it should to break and then increments semaphore. Consumers are waiting for semaphore become greater then 0 and do some work, then waiting again. When producer exited, consumers should finish their work and exit too. I don't understand how can i exit threads which are suspended by semaphore? Here is my code:

```
sem_t ready;

void *prod_routine(void*){
    while(true){
        //do_something
        //here i have if statement with break.
        sem_post(&ready);
    }   
pthread_exit(0);
}

void *cons_routine(void*){
    while(true){
        sem_wait(&ready);
        //do something
    }
pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

pthread_t prod, cons1, cons2;

sem_init(&ready, 0 , 0);

pthread_create(&prod, NULL, &prod_routine, NULL);
pthread_create(&cons1, NULL, &cons_routine, NULL);
pthread_create(&cons2, NULL, &cons_routine, NULL);

pthread_join(prod, NULL);
pthread_join(cons1, NULL);
pthread_join(cons2, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, `sem_wait()` is a cancellation point. Whether this should absolutely be considered a terrible idea is another matter.

Comment: There are some ways.  1) Don't bother, just let the OS terminate the threads at process termination.  2) Give the consumer thread a normally-false boolean 'terminateNow' flag and test it after every sema wait() return.   Just before the producer exits, set the flag and signal the semaphore.  3) If the semaphore is managing a producer-consumer queue, just post a 'poison-pill' message that instructs the consumers to terminate.  The consumer threads get the message, push it back onto the queue and terminate.

Comment: I suppose I should add, at the risk of some devloper's heads exploding, that (1) above is the most reliable mechanism by far. With the others, your app can easily fail to exit.  If one of the threads gets stuck ,either looping or blocked, on some bad task queued to it, then it will not get back to the semaphore and so will not terminate, the main thread gets stuck on the 'join' call-of-death, and your customers have to shut down the process with the Task Manager or 'kill -9'.  Messy, unwanted and avoidable :(

Comment: here is the prototype for `pthread_exit()`  `void pthread_exit(void *retval);`  Notice the parameter is a `void*` not an `int`.  Therefore, each of the calls should be: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how can i exit threads which are suspended by semaphore?

In the most literal sense, you can't.  A thread that is suspended waiting to acquire a semaphore cannot do *anything* until it stops waiting, including terminate.  The primary question, then, is really how to make such threads stop waiting.

There are at least four ways you can accomplish this:

- increment the semaphore so that the thread can acquire it.  This is the cleanest and best approach.  The trick is then to provide a mechanism by which the thread, when it wakes, can recognize that it should terminate instead of proceeding as normal.
- use `sem_timedwait()` instead of `sem_wait()`, and wait for the timeout to expire.  This is a bit dodgy, for although you can determine whether `sem_timedwait()` returned because of a timeout, it's not necessarily clear what the thread should then do about it.
- use `pthread_cancel()` to send a cancellation request to the thread.  This *should* be effective on a thread blocked in a `sem_wait()`, but it's rather heavy-handed.  In particular, it starts a chain of events that leads more or less directly to thread termination.
- send a signal to the thread via `pthread_kill()`.  Be careful, however, for signal dispositions are process-wide.  In particular, then, if the chosen signal's disposition is "stop" or "terminate" (and it is not blocked) then that will affect the whole process.  This relies on the signal not being configured with the `SA_RESTART` flag.

Other than `pthread_cancel()`, all of these have in common the requirement that the thread waiting on the semaphore needs to check when it returns from its wait *why* it returned.  It must check the return value of `sem_[timed]wait()` and possibly the value of `errno`, and it may need to check one or more for-purpose shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

first try with `pthread_kill()`. For this first call `pthread_cancel` and followed by `pthread_kill()` with signal SIGSTOP. Even if after that it is not working for your try to destroy the semaphore with `sem_destroy()`.

Comment: "Destroying  a  semaphore  that  other  processes or threads are currently blocked on (in `sem_wait`(3)) produces undefined behavior."

Comment: Well, that' different.  Why do that?  If the threads are stuck on the semaphore, why not just, well, signal it?

Comment: @MartinJames, the thread will be place on sleep mode by OS. So you can not send a signal to it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am giving this advice because Martin once to do that just before exit from the program. But not a good idea.

Comment: I guess that's a matter of opinion, @Abhijit.  Myself, I cannot recommend ever knowingly invoking undefined behavior.  *By definition* you have no reason to expect it to be of any benefit, whereas you do need to fear that it will be harmful.  And if it turns out to be harmful, there's no good reason to suppose that the harm will be limited to the process wherein the undefined behavior is triggered.

Comment: @Abhijit I meant signal the semaphore, not send a unix signal:)

Comment: Did you try anything from your side?